# How to interpret huge costs in a query plan

Tags: amazon-redshift, sql-execution-plan

At one point in my query plan **the costs explode to a 98 digit number (~2e97)**. First, it is only the upper bound (10^5..2e97) and finally both boundaries (2e97..2e97). At this point, costs do not change anymore if you move further to the top of the plan and thus the plan becomes quite useless. It seems like it reached some saturation.

My interpretation is that the query is **too complicated for the planner to evaluate** it correctly and costs rise till they reach its limit (which would be around 2e97).

**Is this interpretation correct?** Do you have some more information about how this happens and what could be done to improve the query/plan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues here.  One is the actual behaviour of `EXPLAIN`, the other is a bug.

The first issue is that in Postgres, `EXPLAIN` costs are to the maximum extent possible intended to be realistic and be true to the actual, real-world cost and time required by an operation.

This is *not* the case with `EXPLAIN` in Redshift.

In Redshift, costs are *arbitrary numbers*.  They have been selected by the developers, I think in an effort to rather crudely control the query planner.

I can see *no* advantages to this method, and no end of disadvantages, but there it is.  (For example, you can't compare costs across queries - even the same basic query which you're only experimenting with to find the most efficient solution).

So, for example, in Redshift scanning a table has a cost of 1 per row.

Sorting a table has a cost of I think it was 1,000,000,000 (one billion), plus 1 per row - so scanning 1b records is considered cheaper than *sorting one row*, which is nuts.  This is why the query planner goes wrong at times.

The second issue is that there is a bug in the costs presented by `EXPLAIN` with `DS_DIST_BOTH`.  I believe it uses an uninitialized variable, and as a result has a cost which is about a million times more atoms than there are in the Universe.

I *did* try to tell Support.  I tried for a while and then gave up.  You have to understand the limiations of Redshift Support - they don't understand Redshift, and they don't really seem to be able to think very much for themselves.  I came away from the discussion with the view that someone, at some point, had told them plan costs could become very large numbers, and from that point on it became impossible for them to comprehend that there could be a very large number *and it could actually be wrong*.  This is by far not the only bug I have given up trying to get Support to comprehend.

Comment: Many thanks for this comprehensive answer! Actually it happens in the context of DS_BCAST_INNER but this might be the same situation

Comment: My pleasure.  Any chance you could post the SQL and the output from EXPLAIN?  it would be good to confirm you're seeing the same issue, with DS_BCAST_INNER.  It may be I have not fully accurately quantified when the bug manifests.